# FacebookSDK opens in Safari, not in Native app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using facebook sdk which downloaded from this link

[Facebook SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/)

After downloading, I installed embedded it in my app, with help of samples given along with SDK.

Facebook SDK opens Safari but it does not open any login window within app.
I simply want to sign in within app, I don't want to switch app.

How can I do that.

If anything is not clear regarding question, one can ask me comments.

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook iOS SDK will open the Facebook app if it's installed or the site in Safari to do authentication and jump back to your app once authentication has completed. The Facebook SDK doesn't do authentication within your own app.

Comment: Means in any case, it will go and authenticate from installed app in iPhone. right?

Comment: Yes, it will not do it within your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [grabkit tool](https://github.com/pierrotsmnrd/grabKit) in which you will get all the integration done readymade. Download the project and follow the instructions in the readme file.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook SDK 4.0+

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [FBSDKLoginManager new];
login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
```